# How to use @queryparam when using array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, web-services

I am using a restful web service and I was able to display database records using an array. But I am confused on how will I be able to display my desired record. I have here the class where the SQL query is being executed. I am using Advanced Rest Client google chrome application in testing the response and the output. How will I be able to query 'select * from taxi where taxi_plate_no='inputted data''? I am really confused on how will I be able to do it in an array. Please help me. Thank you! :(

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.ws.rs.QueryParam;

import com.taxisafe.objects.Objects;


public class DisplayArrayConnection
{


    public ArrayList<Objects> getDetails(Connection con) throws SQLException{
    ArrayList<Objects> taxiDetailsList = new ArrayList<Objects>();
    PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM taxi");
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
    try
    {
        while(rs.next())
        {
            Objects detailsObject = new Objects();
            detailsObject.setTaxi_name(rs.getString("taxi_name"));
            detailsObject.setTaxi_plate_no(rs.getString("taxi_plate_no"));

            taxiDetailsList.add(detailsObject);

        }
    } catch (SQLException e)
    {       
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return taxiDetailsList;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@QueryParam is annotation used in rest webservices .
And i think here you want to use parameter with your SQL query.

So using parameter in PreparedStatement use following code

```
     public class DisplayArrayConnection
         {

        public ArrayList<Objects> getDetails(Connection con,String taxiNumber) throws SQLException{
        ArrayList<Objects> taxiDetailsList = new ArrayList<Objects>();
        PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM taxi WHERE taxi_plate_no= ?"); 
stmt.addString(1,taxiNumber);
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
        try
        {
            while(rs.next())
            {
                Objects detailsObject = new Objects();
                detailsObject.setTaxi_name(rs.getString("taxi_name"));
                detailsObject.setTaxi_plate_no(rs.getString("taxi_plate_no"));

                taxiDetailsList.add(detailsObject);

            }
        } catch (SQLException e)
        {       
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return taxiDetailsList;
        }

    }
```

> Note: Use parameter taxiNumber or any other parameter you want to
>   retrive data on that parameter
>
> and use setString(position,value); to replace ? with that parameter

Comment: Thank you for your answer. :) from what I understand about using @Queryparam, it is the like textfield on rest service to be able to test it. Will I not use it to test the SQL query?

Comment: I tried and read about your solution, I think it is setting the exact value. Thank you so much!! :) Can't it be possible that it is based from the input of the user?

Comment: Yes you can develop it like that just read user input and pass as aparameter to finction getDetails()

Comment: I'm sorry, can you please give me an example code. Please? :( it can help me a lot.

Comment: It depends from where you are calling this fuction if you are calling from console then System.in() is the option you will found reading code easyly  by simple searching